# tensorflow.lite.python.convert.ConverterError:could not find toco_from_protos binary

Tags: keras, tensorflow-lite

in tensorflow 2.2,i train a mobileNetv1 model,and get a .h5 file, now i want to convert it to a .tflite file for a android app,but i get a error like title . here is my code:

```
model = load_model(h5path)
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
litemodel = converter.convert()
open(litepath,"wb").write(litemodel)
```

here is my error:

```
tensorflow.lite.python.convert.ConverterError: Could not find toco_from_protos binary, make sure your virtualenv bin directory or pip local bin directory is in your path.
In particular, if you have installed TensorFlow with --user, make sure you add the install directory to your path.


For example:
Linux: export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin/
Mac: export PATH=$PATH:~/Library/Python/<version#>/bin

Alternative, use virtualenv.
```

please help me with my puzzle.

The server of Linux system.

Comment: Have u used exactly the code snippets that are provided on official page https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api ????

Comment: the webpage said that this function needs to run on tf-nightly-2.0-preview,but i could not install that by "pip install tf-nightly-2.0-preview",it said that "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tf-nightly-gpu-2.0-preview (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tf-nightly-gpu-2.0-preview
",do you know what problem with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your environment has not finished installing all requirements.

I would suggest if problem persists or at similar issues to check it also at [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) In this environment you can import Tensorflow and Keras libraries like:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as K
import os
import numpy as np
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)

print(tf.__version__)
print(K.__version__)
```

And you are good to make your transformations. For your problem I would use code snippet below:

```
# WHOLE MODEL
tflite_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('my_model.h5')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(tflite_model)
tflite_save = converter.convert()
open("my_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_save)
```

Happy coding!